# how to perform ufsdump backup 2 directory in the same command?

Tags: linux, sunos

I want to write a script that can capture all the output in the log. How to write the script?

below all the command output. How to capture all the output? 
/usr/sbin/ufsdump ucf /dev/rmt/0 /export/home/ztest
DUMP: Writing 63 Kilobyte records
  DUMP: Date of this level 9 dump: Tue Feb 06 01:53:42 2018
  DUMP: Date of last level 0 dump: the epoch
  DUMP: Dumping /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0 (dmap-a1:/) to /dev/rmt/0.
  DUMP: Mapping (Pass I) [regular files]
  DUMP: Mapping (Pass II) [directories]
  DUMP: Estimated 3285760 blocks (1604.38MB).
  DUMP: Dumping (Pass III) [directories]
  DUMP: Dumping (Pass IV) [regular files]
  DUMP: Tape rewinding
  DUMP: 3285700 blocks (1604.35MB) on 1 volume at 3805 KB/sec
  DUMP: DUMP IS DONE
  DUMP: Level 9 dump on Tue Feb 06 01:53:42 2018

Comment: root@ws01-1a# /usr/sbin/ufsdump 0uf export.ufs /home
 DUMP: Writing 32 Kilobyte records
 DUMP: Date of this level 0 dump: Fri Feb 02 13:16:14 2018
 DUMP: Date of last level 0 dump: the epoch
 DUMP: Dumping /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3 (ws01-1a:/home) to export.ufs.
 DUMP: Mapping (Pass I) [regular files]
 DUMP: Mapping (Pass II) [directories]
 DUMP: Estimated 464842 blocks (226.97MB).
 DUMP: Dumping (Pass III) [directories]
 DUMP: Write error 0 blocks into volume 1
 DUMP: NEEDS ATTENTION: Do you want to restart?: ("yes" or "no") no
 DUMP: The ENTIRE dump is aborted.
root@ws01-1a#

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You should add additional information to the question. You can do so by clicking *Edit*. Please don't place additional information in the comments.